# Wordpress ACF Google Maps Inside jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have a slight issue regarding a Google Map inside my jQuery Tabs. There are placed a Google Map inside every tab, but only the map inside the first tab appears as expected. I have been around every post on Stackoverflow related to this issue, but have not found a solution yet. I thought I would make my own thread here if someone is going to have the same problems as I.

The difference with my problem is that I am using the Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress to generate the Google Maps inside the tabs.

Here is the link to the documentation:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

I have used the jQuery code placed on the documentation page.

My jQuery code with the "resize" trigger:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // new_map
  function new_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
      zoom : 16,
      center : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];

    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){
      add_marker( $(this), map );
    });

    // center map
    center_map( map );

    // return
    return map;

  }

  // add_marker
  function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : latlng,
      map : map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
      // create info window
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content : $marker.html()
      });

      // show info window when marker is clicked
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
      });
    }

  }

  // center_map
  function center_map( map ) {

  // vars
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // loop through all markers and create bounds
  $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
    bounds.extend( latlng );
  });

  // only 1 marker?
  if( map.markers.length == 1 )
  {
    // set center of map
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
    map.setZoom( 16 );
  }
  else
  {
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
  }

}

// document ready
var map = null;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#tabs').tabs(); // Creates jQuery Tabs

  $('.acf-map').each(function(){
    // create map
    map = new_map( $(this) );
  });



  $('.contact-nav > li > a').one('focus', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  });

});

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" class="content">

  <div class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-1" class="tab_content">
    <!-- ACF Google Map here -->
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2" class="tab_content">
    <!-- ACF Google Map here -->
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-3" class="tab_content">
    <!-- ACF Google Map here -->
  </div>

</div>
```

I cannot provide the code for the ACF Google Map html element since it is generated by the ACF Plugin, which is a big snippet of code. I would have provided with a test page, but I do not have a server to host the Wordpress site.

I hope that someone have the knowledge to assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're dealing with isn't really an ACF issue, but rather a Google Maps/CSS/JS issue. What happens is, when the tab is out of view, it is considered "0" height. So when it becomes active, it doesn't know to change the height. Others have recommended using a listener on the tab (especially if the framework supports it natively like Foundation's reflow), but Google Maps, I'm not sure updates to that. I have yet to find a tried/true method.